# Asterisk IVR setup: disallow direct dial for some extensions?

Tags: asterisk, pbx, freepbx, elastix

We've got PBX to configure. It's based on Elastix 2.4.0, freePBX 2.8.1 and Asterisk 1.8.20.0.

Currently we have a setup for inbound calls like that:

```
Inbound call > Announcement (30 sec) > IVR (no sound, for extension dial only, 5 sec) > Queue (for timeout on IVR, aka Callcenter)
```

Boss wants me to do some tuning: disallow external caller to dial certain extensions directly (like 141, 142, etc.) so the only way they (callers) could get to these numbers if someone (like 140) will patch them through first.

Could you suggest me what needs to be done? I've been configuring through Elastix until now, so if it should be done other way, extensive directions would help me a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the docs and can you cite the relevant items that are causing you difficulty?

Comment: Well, I've tried a lot, but only in Elastix since I've got no experience in configuring Asterisk by editing files. And I simply see no way how it can be done through web interface. There is a check box in IVR config page "Enable Direct Dial" which is checked, but no thing like "List of available extensions for Direct Dial" or "List of prohibited extensions for Direct Dial". So the simple question is: how do I disallow external caller do dial 141, but allow do dial 140? I simply have no idea how that could be realized, so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 1):

FreePBX is at version 2.11 now, with 2.12 imminent. You really want to update your system. In current versions you can specify a list of extensions that can be direct dialed from an IVR by creating a directory containing the appropriate extensions.

I believe older versions only have a checkbox to allow or disallow direct dialing. If you disallow direct dialing you would need to enter the extensions you want to be able to dial as entries in the IVR. Perhaps the directory option is available in older versions as well. Do you have the directory module installed?

Comment: I'm not sure about module. However, I've found solution: Simply adding certain extensions to IVR respond options and making them hangup call does the trick. For some reason I was thinking this things where accepting one symbol input only, apparently it's not. It could be used to intercept dialed extensions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution: Simply adding certain extensions to IVR respond options and making them hangup call does the trick. For some reason I was thinking this things where accepting one symbol input only, apparently it's not. It could be used to intercept dialed extensions as well.